# Data feed that shows individual orders

Tags: data, market-data, order, feed

Does anyone know how I can obtain time and sales data for a stock?

Lots of feeds provide the total volume but I would like to see the breakdown of what buy/sell orders made up the day's volume.

I would like to get this via an API so I can analyze it in my code in real time as the market is trading.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just call-up a stock exchange and ask for their historical quotes. The bigger exchanges will want money, but the smaller exchanges may mail you a hard drive for free.

Comment: time and sales..

Comment: @chrisay - i need an api i can invoke so i have real-time analytics.  will update my question

Comment: @cdcaveman - ok, so i am looking for time and sales data.. will update the question

Comment: @dev Most exchanges have a full order-book feed, though they arrive as binary data rather than via an API.

Comment: @chrisaycock yup the big exchanges will send you a DVD's with full-order book info from every month, of the previous month

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you're referring to US equities.)

Most normalized, vendor data feeds that you see are sourced from the CTA/UTP SIPs, which don't provide breakdown of individual orders.

To see the composition of individual orders, you'd need either a prop feed or a normalized feed derived from a prop feed. Such prop feeds include the Nasdaq TotalView-ITCH, NYSE Integrated etc. Aside from sourcing these prop feeds from the venue directly, you can also do so via one of their extranet providers (e.g. Pico, Options IT, Fixnetix, TNS). There are several providers that normalize these feeds, such as Databento (disclaimer: which I work for), Celoxica, Redline.

Answer (score 0):

Which stock are you looking for? Try checking out [IEX Cloud](https://iexcloud.io). They have a wide range of core and premium data delivered through APIs. If you're looking at stocks in the US markets, [AlgoSeek](https://algoseek.com) is also an option.